# android-support-v7-appcompat library error

Tags: android

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQPvV.png)

I want to use android support v7 appcompat library in my android project. So I import v7 library project folder and also make "configure path". But I can't use v7 library project and become the error (shown in image). I use Eclipse Oxygen version. How can I solve this problem? I need some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Invalidate Caches and Restart` and start again your project.

Answer (score 0):

Use Android Studio. Eclipse is no longer supported by Android and you will save many headaches like this if you use the studio.